# Issue in electron with Usb binding configuration?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm, electron

I am facing an issue to install USB modules in my electron app. When i tried to install electron and their dependency i'm getting below issues always.  Please someone help me to achieve this.

if any one does same thing please provide any link or instruction document it will helps me to move forwards.

```
> master-electron@1.0.0 install C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\master-electron
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\master-electron>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\ranganathan.e\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON

gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\master-electron
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! master-electron@1.0.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the master-electron@1.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-26T13_40_04_660Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According logs that provided by you, It says build script can't find Python. Electron uses node-gyp for build itself, that needs to install python and Visual Studio Build Tools.

I recommend to you install `windows-build-tools` on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools). It can installed by using command `npm install --global windows-build-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your module uses node-gyp - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp - and node-gyp needs platform compilers. Read more about these requiremens here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

If you developer box is running Windows you can install the needed compiler:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.13.6
npm info using node@v12.14.1

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\ranganathan.e\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.13.6 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```